# Pointer to Pointer with Custom Struct

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, struct

I Have a similar issue like the one listed here [pointer-to-a-pointer-to-a-struct-giving-headache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395391/pointer-to-a-pointer-to-a-struct-giving-headache)
my issue is different because i don't want multi instances from LISTOFONES i want Multi instances of ONE's Pointers like

```
class ONE {  
    int id;  
    char *name;  
};

class LISTOFONES {
    ONE **pointers;
    char *name;

    LISTOFONES ();
    ~LISTOFONES ();
};
```

What to do to have a correct and memory safe initialization of the pointers variable with
1- pure c++ .. not stl containers
2- 100% dynamic not [] array limitation
3- Completely Memory Safe ( All Pointers safely point to a valid class too )

**EDIT:**
This is Not Home Work
and For what i want i only want to know what is the method to correctly init the pointers in the 'pointers' variable

**EDIT**
I Am trying to Achieve a Pointer List (array) Pointed by the Pointer *pointers*
Each Pointer points to the *ONE* struct

Comment: "STL containers" qualify as pure C++, since they're defined in the C++ language standard. There's no good reason to avoid them unless this is homework, in which case you should say so and tag your question as such.

Comment: stl containers are pure c++ :)

Comment: It's not clear why you want `LISTOFONES::pointers` to be a `ONE**` rather than a `ONE*`. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: You are posting decelerations without code, and no explanation of the problem you are having. Please elaborate.

Comment: @ildjarn - I suppose he wants to be able to grow his array. Copying pointers will be cheaper than copying objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were me, I would allocate an array of `ONE*`s thus:

```
pointers = new ONE*[reserve];
```

I would arrange that the first several members of the `pointers` array pointed to valid ONE objects. The last remaining members would all be zero (not essential, since they will never be derferenced.)

When I needed to grow the array, I would call new with a bigger size:

```
newPointers = new ONE*[newReserve];
```

and I would copy all of the pointers from previous array to the new array.

```
void
LISTOFONES::push_back(const ONE& one) {
  if(_size>=_reserve) {
    std::size_t newReserve = _reserve?(_reserve*2):1;
    ONE** newPointers = new ONE*[newReserve];
    std::copy(this->pointers, this->pointers+_size, newPointers);
    std::fill(newPointers+_size, newPointers+newReserve, (ONE*)0);
    std::swap(this->pointers, newPointers);
    _reserve = newReserve;
    delete[] newPointers;
  }
  this->pointers[_size] = new ONE(one);
  ++_size;
}
```